# Pointer to deque<int>::push_back

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;
main()
{
    typedef void (deque<int>::*func_ptr)(int);
    func_ptr fptr = &deque<int>::push_back;
}
```

Im trying to get pointer to this function but I get a compilation error

```
error: cannot convert ‘void (std::deque<int>::*)(const value_type&) {aka void (std::deque<int>::*)(const int&)}’ to ‘func_ptr {aka void (std::deque<int>::*)(int)}’ in initialization
     func_ptr fptr = &deque<int>::push_back;
```

I want to do this so that I can get pointer to different member functions on the basis of different conditions.

I referred [this link](http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/Pointers_to_memberfuncs.pdf).

Comment: The lecture notes you've linked are no longer publicly accessible.

Comment: @ti7 I'm still able to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push_back()` takes a `const T &` parameter, as the error message states:

> cannot convert ‘void (std::deque::*)(const value_type&) ...

Change your type alias to:

```
typedef void (deque<int>::*func_ptr)(const int &);
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - using `auto` will be a compilation error here, because the function is overloaded, and auto won't know which overload to associate with the given function name.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the accepted answer, the problem is that the type signature is different -- for a `std::deque<T>`, `push_back` only has an overload that accepts `T const&`, and not `T` directly.  `typedef void (deque<int>::*func_ptr)(const int &)` is a perfectly concise and cromulent way to write this.

I wanted to address a C++11 way to do this -- type aliases.  One may first wonder "why not use `auto`?"  This is not possible because the function being accessed is an overloaded function, and `auto` does not know which of the overloads to access.  Because the original question embeds the knowledge of the function type being `void(int)`, the statement `&deque<int>::push_back` selects the correct overload.  The problem with the simpler statement is that it bakes in knowledge of the container and the type being contained.  If you want to change to a `std::vector`, or from `int` to `short`, you'll have to make all new types.  With type aliases, we can templatize everything to avoid embedding type knowledge:

```
using func_ptr = void(Cont::*)(typename Cont::const_reference);
```

We can do something simple, as before:

```
func_ptr<deque<int>> fptr = &deque<int>::push_back;
```

...or we can refer to a container somewhere:

```
vector<short> container;
```

...looking up its type at compile time, and storing a pointer to its `push_back` function, all without caring what the container is:

```
using container_type = decltype(container);
func_ptr<container_type> fptr2 = &container_type::push_back;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a bigger problem with what you are trying to do. Implementations are allowed to add default parameters to any member functions, so the actual signature for `push_back()` might be different. It can even add additional functions with the same name (but a different signature).

I advise against taking pointers to container members function. You are usually better of without it.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but I suspect the reason was because the response didn't address the original question of how the OP should get a pointer to this function.  Likely, an answer plus your proscription to the OP's approach probably would have been left alone.  Again, I didn't do it. :)